# react-native-fbsdk resumeLoginWithResult invoked with invalid lockIdentifier: got 0, expected 0

Tags: react-native

I've recently added react-native-fbsdk to my project and am attempting to use the standard Login.js file as shown in the git repo example.

```js
var Login = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={this.props.style}>
        <FBSDKLoginButton
          style={styles.loginButton}
          onWillLogin={() => {
            FBSDKAccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken((result) => {
              if (result == null) {
                alert('Start logging in.');
              } else {
                alert('Start logging out.');
              }
            });
            return true;
          }}
          onLoginFinished={(error, result) => {
            if (error) {
              alert('Error logging in.');
            } else {
              if (result.isCancelled) {
                alert('Login cancelled.');
              } else {
                alert('Logged in.');
              }
            }
          }}
          onLogoutFinished={() => alert('Logged out.')}
          readPermissions={[]}
          publishPermissions={[]}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
});
```

As far as I can tell FBSDKLoginButton works until it invokes onWillLogin, then an error appears in xcode:

> [RCTFBSDKLoginButtonManager.m:132] resumeLoginWithResult invoked with
>   invalid lockIdentifier: got 0, expected 0

It got the exact integer that it expected right? What gives?

I've looked at the line in the .m file as well as FBSDKLoginButton.ios.js and don't see anything that would trigger an error.

My hunch is that there is some esoteric setting in [developers.facebook](https://developers.facebook.com) or xcode that is culprit.

What say you good StackOverflowers?